# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error when loading data into seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, seaborn

I'm trying to load data from a github page (it's part of the standard seaborn datasets you can get.) I am on PyCharm and I don't understand what the hell is going on.

```
import seaborn as sns

data = sns.load_dataset("tips")
```

Then I get the error. Why am I getting this error?

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.7 "/Users/shahbhuiyan/Desktop/PyCharm Projects/Pandas/pycharmtest.py"

urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)>
```

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error

Answer (score 15):

I encountered the same issue and found the solution here: 
http://www.programmersought.com/article/2877138500/

Basically, just add these two lines of code, then try importing the data set:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```

This way, python will ignore verification of the security certificate

Comment: As a workaorund, it works but this actually disables the certificate verification. right?

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal of MAC OS and try this command:
"/Applications/Python 3.6/Install Certificates.command"

This works for me because Python 3.6 on MacOS uses an embedded version of OpenSSL, which does not use the system certificate store. More details here.

Answer (score 0):

By [mwaskom](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2418#issuecomment-755268016), we know that

> `load_dataset` pulls in csv files from https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data and your system is failing to make a secure connection to it.

So, we can first download dataset from https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data on our browser, and denote the path to the dataset directory by `/path/to/seaborn-data`, then we can let

```
data = sns.load_dataset('tips', data_home='/path/to/seaborn-data')
```

This way we can work around the issue produced by security certification without any risky side effect.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS, for me the following worked on the command line:

First do this:
`pip install certifi`

And then do this, depending on your python version:
`/Applications/Python\ 3.12/Install\ Certificates.command`

Now you can get your seaborn datasets.

More info can be found in this question + answers:
[urllib and "SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED" Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error)